# What exactly is 'computer mathematics'?

Tags: computer-science, computational-mathematics

I'm looking at some potential things to study next semester and I see a full B.sc. degree called 'Computer mathematics'. It says it's a hybrid between computer-science and mathematics.

Does anyone have any experience with this degree? If so, how much mathematics is taught compared to, say, physics or a mathematics B.sc.? What kind of computer-science is involved?

What kind of problems/projects will I be working on with this sort of degree?

Comment: I haven't heard of this degree... do you mind sharing a link to the degree plan at whatever college you found this?  (Just for an example of what sort of degree this would be...)

Comment: @ Paze: Sounds like a spin-off from the more general Computational Science, which are gaining popularity.

Comment: I've never heard of it before either, and I could think of more than one thing that it could mean.  I think it would be best to ask someone at your school.

Comment: I'm afraid my school is Icelandic. That's why I'm trying to get an idea of what this is in English so I could read up on it.

I'll link anyways since you asked.

http://www.ru.is/td/grunnnam/bs-i-tolvunarstaerdfraedi/

Comment: There was a similar degree at the school I went to called computational mathematics or something similar...  A friend of mine completed that degree, but this is in Washington state, USA.